# Аутентификация на платных прокси в java

Tags: java, proxy, аутентификация, okhttp

В python есть простой рабочий код через requests:

```
proxies = {'http': 'http://login:password@ip:port',
           'https': 'https://login:password@ip:port'}
response = requests.post(target_url, data=json_data, headers=some_headers, proxies=proxies)
```

В java тоже самое:

```
Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
        public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
            String credential = Credentials.basic("login", "password");
            return response.request().newBuilder()
                    .header("Proxy-Authorization", credential)
                    .build();
        }
    };

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(ip, port)))
            .proxyAuthenticator(auth)
            .build();

    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    try {
        postdata.put("param", "value");
    } catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), data.toString());

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(target_url)
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .build();
    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

код python успешно аутентифицируется на прокси получает данные с target_url, код java получает 407 "Proxy Authentication Required"

что я делаю не так?

пс: забыл добавить: запрос - HTTPS

Addon:
В Wireshark вот что:
OkHttp:
запрос:

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
CONNECT somehost.ru:443 HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: somehost.ru:443\r\n
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
User-Agent: okhttp/3.8.0\r\n
```

ответ:

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
HTTP/1.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required\r\n
Proxy-Authenticate: Basic realm="proxy"\r\n
Proxy-Connection: close\r\n
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n
File Data: 255 bytes
Line-based text data: text/html
<html><head><title>407 Proxy Authentication Required</title></head>\r\n
<body><h2>407 Proxy Authentication Required</h2><h3>Access to requested resource disallowed by administrator or you need valid username/password to use this resource</h3></body></html>
```

второй запрос:

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
CONNECT somehost.ru:443 HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: somehost.ru:443\r\n
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
User-Agent: okhttp/3.8.0\r\n
Proxy-Authorization: Basic cnAzMDcwOTQzOlA0WWtuMmM4bFM=\r\n
```

но к этому моменту уже java.net.protocolexception и до HandShake дело не доходит.

А вот Python requests:
запрос:

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
CONNECT somehost:443 HTTP/1.0\r\n
Proxy-Authorization: Basic cnAzMDcwOTQzOlA0WWtuMmM4bFM=\r\n
```

ответ:

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\n
```

Почему OkHttp не шлет сразу Proxy-Authorization?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490057/android-okhttp-with-basic-authentication